# Moq setups and closures

Tags: c#, unit-testing, closures, moq

Using Moq, I'm trying to setup a method to return something depending on the argument.
So, if you pass argument1, you'll get result1 back, and if you pass argument2 you'll get result2:

```
var obj = "";

var propertyMock1 = new Mock<PropertyInfo>();
var propertyMock2 = new Mock<PropertyInfo>();

var result1 = "";
var result2 = "";

var factoryMock = new Mock<IFactory>();
factoryMock.Setup(f => f.Create(obj, propertyMock1.Object)).Returns(result1);
factoryMock.Setup(f => f.Create(obj, propertyMock2.Object)).Returns(result2);
```

However, when I call `factoryMock.Object.Create(obj, propertyMock1.Object)`, the return value is `null`.
If I pass `propertyMock2.Object`, it works as expected.

I have no idea why the first setup is not working.

ReSharper is giving me a few hints though, which I don't understand.
On the first setup, it says "Implicitly captured closure: property2" and on the second setup it says "Implicitly captured closure: property1".

Why would each lambda be capturing the other lambda's argument? How are they even related?
And why is the first setup not working?

Comment: Are sure you're relating exactly to the code you've pasted? For example, there is no "property2" in your code.

Comment: How do you call the `Create()` method? It doesn't seem like a likely design to have the same mocked class called with two different mocked values by the code under test. Do you have constructor injection that passes in a sequence or array or two side-by-side PropertyInfos? See my answer below for a possible solution.

Comment: @BartoszKP: My bad, I meant "propertyMock2".

Comment: @KeithPayne: The class under test takes an object, reads its properties and then uses the factory to create another object for each property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's another way to setup a mocked method to react differently to different inputs:

```
var obj = "";

var propertyMock1 = new Mock<PropertyInfo>();
var propertyMock2 = new Mock<PropertyInfo>();

var result1 = "";
var result2 = "";

var factoryMock = new Mock<IFactory>();
factoryMock.Setup(f => f.Create(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<PropertyInfo>())).Returns<string, PropertyInfo>((s, pi) => {
    if (pi == propertyMock1.Object)
        return result1;
    if (pi == propertyMock2.Object)
        return result2;
});

// factoryMock.Setup(f => f.Create(obj, propertyMock2.Object)).Returns(result2);
```

I always have to remind myself that there are other flavors of Returns that includes generic types.

Comment: I get an exception when I actually call the Create method: `System.Reflection.TargetParameterCountException : Parameter count mismatch.`

Comment: Edited to account for the first parameter.